In order to multiply the int array elements, code works fine, but if I change while condition to (arrn[i] != '\0') it gives big number like '25199232'
The below code works fine for the moment and multiply all the numbers to give the answer 6 in this example, just want to understand the while statement is not working if I use  (arrn[i] != '\0')  or (arr) or (arr != 0) it gives wrong output.
int perm(int arrn[])
{
    int i =0;
    int z;
    int t = 1;
    int result =1;
    while(arrn[i] < 9){
        z = arrn[i];
        t = t * z;
        //printf("%d", z);
        i++;
    }
printf("%d", t);
}

int main()
{
    
    int list1[] = {1,2,3};
    perm(list1);
    
}


The condition arr != 0 would only be useful if the end of the array were marked with an element with the value 0. If you change int list1[] = {1,2,3}; to int list1[] = {1,2,3,0};, then this condition should work. However, it would probably be better to pass the length of the array to the function perm, as described in the answer.

Once i is 3 you're reading past the end of the array.  Neither of your two conditions prevent that from happening.  Doing so triggers undefined behavior in your code.
When you have undefined behavior, there is no guarantee what your code will do.  It might crash, it might output strange results (as the case of your alternate definition does), or it might appear to work properly (as it does in your original code).
You need to pass in the size of the array to the function, then use that to determine when to stop iterating.

Thank you Paul and dbush, your comments are appreciated and useful, actually it was the undefined behavior without defining the size of the int array that was causing the problem and now by adding the size argument in function, it is working fine.

You could just initialize list1 as {1,2,3,9} but it's pretty odd to use 9 as a terminator.

@PaulLynch honestly that doesn't sound like a good idea unless in his function or program he specifically decides that 9 is for whatever reason a special value that indicates termination (and in this case it is, but still). But to me it seems an unnecessary roundabout way to avoid doing the right thing which is also the simplest, that is to pass the array size to the function.

@rdxdkr I agree, hence my comment. Since OP's code explicitly stops looping through the array at 9 or greater - who knows why - using 9 as a terminator gives his expected result. But passing in the number of elements in arrn is a better solution, allowing any number of operands of any value (ignoring overflow).
